# Let $f$ differentiable 3 times in $\mathbb{R}$, and $f(0)=0 , f'(1)=f(1)=f'(0)=1$. Prove that exist $c\in (0,1)$ such that $f^{(3)}(c)=0$

Tags: calculus, functions

> Let $f$ differentiable 3 times in $\mathbb{R}$, and $f(0)=0 ,
>  f'(1)=f(1)=f'(0)=1$ prove that there exists $c\in(0,1)$ such that
>   $f^{(3)}(c)=0$.

My question is: Can I say that By Rolle's exist $c\in(0,1)$ such that $f^{(2)}(c)=0$ because $f'(1)=f'(0)=1$ and for the third Differentiable of the same $c\in(0,1)$ it gives $0$ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. You can not conlude that $f''(c)=0$ implies $f'''(c)=0.$ (Counterexample: $f(x)= \sin x$ and $c=0$.)

We have $f(1)=1$ and $f(0)=0.$ By the mean value theorem, there is $x_1 \in (0,1)$ such that $f'(x_1)=1.$ By Rolle, we get $x_2 \in (0,x_1)$ and $x_3 \in (x_1,1)$ such that

$$f''(x_2)=f''(x_3)=0.$$

Again , by Rolle: there is $c \in (x_2,x_3)$ such that

$$f'''(c)=0.$$

Comment: How does $f(0)=0$ and $f(1)=1$ implies that $f'(x_1)=0$?

Comment: Ooops, pardon. We have $f'(x_1)=1.$